# Softlink or hardlink a Linux remote folder in Windows

Tags: untagged

The thing is that, our codebase is located on a remote server, that, we access it through a VPN with putty. The server is in CentOs. I was wondering if its possible to softlink or hardlink this folder so that I can access it like a regular directory within windows.

I dont want to be pushing and pulling stuff from the server every time I want to test something, and I need more than the available tools from the centos command line.

Comment: Why not using local VMs? Sounds like a terrible way to do development.

Comment: Are you using rsync? If not, give it a try. Unless you have a *horribly* slow connection, it should sync in less than a second. If you *do* have a horribly slow connection, the "hard link" you seek won't make things any easier on you.

Comment: you have to run rsync every time you want changes to be reflected

Comment: I agree that its a terrible way to work. I will propose a new approach for the project, but, it is what it is today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the VPN. If you always leave the VPN open, then theoretically you can export the remote filesystem in a format your local Windows host can understand. In this case, you would mount it under your local filesystem and symlink it as you see fit. For this you would use Samba.

The other option is to place the codebase under some repository control such as Git or Subversion, and then use a git or subversion client on Windows to access it. Here again, you would need the VPN to be open all the time, or at least those periods where you need access.

Apart from that, you don't have any other choice than to "push and pull" the code every time you need it.

Comment: +1 Was just going to off up the source control option also

Comment: I will go with Samba and try to set it up. The project is already on versioning system, but I dont want to clutter the log with tons of debugging commits.

Comment: so you want to edit the master codebase directly, bypassing the versioning? that doesn't sound good

Comment: No, the code that I will be editing is the one on my own repo, the thing is that the code is on a remote server (dont ask, I know it sucks, but, thats the environment Im stuck with on this project). I just want to be able to use the code as if it were on my machine, so I can use an IDE, and do my work there, and, once Im done with it just commit my changes (this will be done through ssh or maybe some GUI Tool).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [simple SCP client, WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) or install SAMBA on CentOS and access the Linux file system from Windows.

Comment: across a vpn? no. this will only work if the vpn is always left open

Comment: Yes. Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use SVN over HTTPS ?

Comment: More detail would improve your answer.